# updating ids that have duplicate records in both the tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables

Emp

```
Empid      postid       postcodeid
    1           1             null
    2           1             null
    3           1             null
```

2nd table 
Postcode

```
Postcodeid       postid      
         1            1
         2            1
         3            1
```

Now i want to update postcodeid with 2nd table ids.
Like the below table

```
Empid      postid       postcodeid
    1           1                1
    2           1                2
    3           1                3
```

Comment: But how are both tables connected? The value for `postid` is the same for each row, therefore, there seems to be no 1:1 relation.

Comment: Ya 1 : 1 relation is not there but for the same postcodeid i ve to generate like this.any cursor or while loop can we use?

Comment: @ChaituMeher how would you want to update the tables without any same unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Run an `Update` query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.postcodeid=table2.postcodeid
WHERE table1.empid= table2.empid
```

Comment: table2 does not seem to have an `empid` column.

Comment: You are right, I'm wondering if its a mistake, otherwise i'm not sure how the OP would want to update the table.

Comment: Its not a mistake 2nd table doesnt have empid column

Comment: So please clarify based on what you want to update your first table.

Comment: Based on postid if it is matching to the 2nd table postid it has to update with 1 ,2 and 3 postcodeid like a while loop  and exit from the loop.can it be done?

Comment: There are (at least) three matching rows in the second table. Which of them is the right one?

Comment: Ya both the table postid column is having duplicates but in the emp table it has to update like a while loop and exit

Comment: Can we run a cursor to update the postcodeid 1 by 1 ...using postid?